# HighChart xAxis and data discrepancy

Tags: highcharts

There is some xAxis and data discrepancy, for example the second curve I need to be pictured as 2014-03 and 2014-04., but it drawn 2013-11; 2013-12
[image: my graph]

Is there exist some method where HighChart gets data in pairs, because in this case I have folowing json: [{"name":"xAxis","data":["2013-11","2013-12","2014-01","2014-02","2014-03","2014-04"]},{"name":"FIRSTname"","data":[81568256,93170615,92267597,97838553,103930539,103268030]},{"name":"SECONDname"","data":[20705697,23387653]}]

And I don't know how to inform HighChart "Hey, buddy, plz draw this curve from '2014-03' to '2014-04' for example.
Or something like "data": ['not draw this point', '1234', 'not draw this point', '1234']
So in this case he can easily understand that '1234' is for '2013-12', because it goes second.
Thanks

Comment: In the second serie data, points require to be pairs [x,y] instaed of y value. As a result use it: {"name":"SECONDname"","data":[[4,20705697],[5,23387653]]}]

Comment: Can you write it to as answer and I accept it, or maybe delete question? I think it is useful for people who google it. Thanks!

Comment: I did it, so lets mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second serie data, points require to be pairs [x,y] instaed of y value. As a result use it: {"name":"SECONDname"","data":[[4,20705697],[5,23387653]]}]

Answer (score 1):

Use `null` for data you don't want the chart to show

```
data: [null, 1234, null, 1234]
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ks22pgja/